# Error while trying to push the data in observable stream. Angular

Tags: angular

when i am trying to push data into data stream from

observable i get error that my observer is undefined. code is below:

```
@Injectable()

export class CategoryService {

public category:Subject<Category>;

public categories:Observable<Category[]>;

private categoriesObserver:any;

  constructor(private authHttpService:AuthHttpService,private authService:AuthService) {


    this.categories = new Observable(observer=> 

    {this.categoriesObserver = observer}).share();

this.category = new BehaviorSubject<Category>(null); }



 getAll() {



   console.log(this.categoriesObserver);

    return this.authHttpService

    .get('/api/categories', { headers: contentHeaders })

    .map((res: Response) => res.json())

    .map((data) => {


      var categories = data.map((category) => {

        return new Category(

          category._id,

          category.name,

          category.description,

          category.owner,

          category.collaborators

        );

      });


     this.categoriesObserver.next(categories);


      return categories;
```

so the app gives an error this.categoriesObserver is undefined.and if i try to define it beforehand i get error that next() is not a function. what can it possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error was caused by the fact that i was pushing data into observable rather than into subject which works.